# encoding XDCAM MXF with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Trying to encode XDCAM HD422 MXF with FFMPEG
But can't know specific setting for encoder/format/mux
Anyone can show me sample code or give some advice for that ?

Comment: why not use avformat_alloc_output_context2() to guess the format for you from the extension "mxf"?

Answer (score 2):

When you don't know exactly how to set up some container and/or codec, always use `avformat_alloc_output_context2()` to guess the format for you from the file extension ("mxf" in this case), so you get a start point!

```
AVFormatContext * formatContext( 0 );
avformat_alloc_output_context2( &formatContext, 0, 0, "anything.mxf" );
```

When you do this, `formatContext` will have the **default** codecs already set up, take them with:

- `m_formatContext->oformat->video_codec`
- `m_formatContext->oformat->audio_codec`

For "mxf", the default audio/video codecs **AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO** and **AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE**

But, **default** setup is not enough in this case. You have a specific camera model. So, with some sample video you can check the EXACT format/codec using `ffprobe some_sample.mxf`

I found those samples here: http://www.hamburgpromedia.com/Testfiles/MXF_MPEG_Testfiles.php

- XDCAM_HD422_720p50.mxf
- XDcam_HD4221080i50.mxf

FFprobe tells me the video codec is the same as the default for "mxf" (**AV_CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO**), but the audio codec is **AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S24LE**.

So, what to do now? Just change the audio_codec:

```
m_formatContext->oformat->audio_codec = AV_CODEC_ID_PCM_S24LE;
```

Ready! You have the same format and codecs of your camera! Just go on and create the audio/video streams, open de codecs, etc, etc...

Comment: OP specifically mentioned he wants XDCAM HD422, not just anything that happens to fit in an mxf container.

Comment: sure... but he can try some of the possible combinations, according to the wikipedia table

Comment: I updated the answer! Instead of get information from wikipedia. It's better use a sample video from this exact model.